# Better way to insert unique record using Sequelize JS

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I was wondering if there is a better way to check the database first if the record that I am about to insert exist to avoid duplicates. In that way I can insert records that are only UNIQUE.

Right now what I did is used to raw query via if statement to check the database and if it passes the condition that is where I insert the record:

```
const addName = function(name, amount) {
  sequelize.query(`SELECT * FROM names WHERE name="${name}"`, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
    .then(names => {
      if (names.length === 0) {
        sequelize.query(
          `INSERT INTO names (name, amount) VALUES('${name}','${amount}')`, {
            type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT
          }
        ).then(function (data) {
          console.log('inserted STEAMER data---> ', data); 
        });
      } else {
        console.log('Duplicate records >>>>>>');
      }
    });
};
```

Is there any alternative to do this via Sequelize JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You've to use ORM way of Sequelize and just to call `findOrCreate` method on model.

Example:

1) `db.js`:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('mysql://user:pass@127.0.0.1:3306/dbname');

const Name = sequelize.define('Name', {
  name: {
   type: Sequelize.STRING,
   allowNull: false,
   unique: true 
  },
  amount: {
   type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(10, 2), // or .INTEGER
   allowNull: false,
   defaultValue: 0
  }
}, {
  tableName: 'names', 
  timestamps: false, 
  freezeTableName: true
});

// extending model with method
Name.upsert = (name, amount) => {
  const find = {name};
  const create = {name, amount};
  return Name.findOrCreate({where: find, defaults: create});
};

module.exports = {sequelize, models: {Name}};
```

2) `app.js` (in expressjs example) :

```
const db = require('./db');
const Name = db.models.Name;

app.post('/names', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const amount = req.body.amount;
    const result = await Name.upsert(name, amount);
    res.status(200).send(result);
  }
  catch (error) {
     res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
```

Read [this getting started](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started.html) and save Your day with ready to use methods of Sequelize ORM